# Demons vs. Devils?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, monsters, campaign-settings

I come across Demons in 13th Age, and Devils in the 13 True Ways, and sort of know that such distinctions exist in d20 games. In D20 games, what are the differences between demons and devils, and do they work together or do they oppose each other?

Comment: This is too broad as-is. Restrict it to one specific setting (such as d&d) vs all D20 based fantasy games.

Comment: Even within D&D, the answer may be drastically different depending on the edition (SSD's answer below, for example, has almost nothing to do with D&D 4e which doesn't even *have* the concept of "lawful evil.")

Comment: Yep, and at least in 5e they use some of the same methods. This just isn't answerable across every edition.

Answer (score 6):

In D&D, demons and devils are distinct in that demons are *chaotic* and devils are *lawful*. Both evil of course, but opposite ends of the evil spectrum.

Having opposite approaches to evil, they have completely opposed goals and methods. They don't get along and don't cooperate. At least in editions of D&D with the Great Wheel cosmology, demons (aka Tanar'ri) and devils (aka Baatezu) have been at war for time out of memory, in a conflict popularly known as the [Blood War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_War).

This is all particular to D&D, of course. It's possible (and sometimes likely) that the nature of devils and demons in D&D and d20 games have inspired some parts of other games, but their relationship in D&D is *so very specific* that it can't be reliably or directly extrapolated to any other game.